# Residue of $\cot z $ at $z= 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, residue-calculus

I need to calculate the **Residue** of $\cot z$ at the pole $0$ . Now, I think that the order of the pole is $1$. But I do not know how to show it. So, assuming the order of pole to be $1$, I calculated the residue as follows - $$ \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} (z - 0) \cot z  = \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos z}{\frac{\sin z}{z}} = \frac{\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \cos z}{\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin z}{z}} = 1$$  Is my answer right? Again back to the main question, how do I determine or show the order of a pole(in general) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your answer is right.

In general, assume to have two holomorphic functions $f$, $g$ with a zero at $z_0$. Assume $z_0$ is a zero of multiplicity $p$ of $f$ and multiplicity $q$ of $g$, then $z_0$ is a pole of order $q-p$ of $f/g$. If $q-p \leq 0$, the singularity is removable.

Here $0$ is a zero of multiplicity $1$ of $\sin(z)$ (since it doesn't cancel the derivative) and is a zero of multiplicity $0$ of $\cos(z)$ (since it doesn't cancel the cosine itself). Thus, it is a pole of order $1-0$ of $\frac{\cos(z)}{\sin(z)}.$

Comment: By multiplicity you mean order?

Comment: Yes, I mean $z_0$ is a zero of multiplicity/order $p$ of $f$ if it cancels $f$, $f'$, ... $f^{(p-1)}$ but not $f^{(p)}$.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct, and here is another way to try, in particular when taking derivatives or limits can be a little troublesome, and using the fact that we're *only interested* in low powers of $\;z\;$ in power or Laurent series since we want to find out something at $\;z=0\;$:

$$\frac{\cos z}{\sin z}=\frac{1-\frac{z^2}2+\ldots}{z-\frac{z^3}6+\ldots}=\frac{1-\frac{z^2}2+\ldots}{z\left(1-\frac{z^2}6+\ldots\right)}=\frac1z\left(1-\frac{z^2}2+\ldots\right)\left(1+\frac{z^2}6+\frac{z^4}{36}+\ldots\right)=$$

You can see the above two parentheses are *power series* and thus analytic, so in order to find out what the coefficient of $\;z^{-1}\;$ is we just do

$$=\frac1z\left(1-\frac{z^3}3+\ldots\right)=\frac1z+\ldots$$

and thus the residue is certainly $\;1\;$ .

Comment: How did you get from $\left(\sum\limits_{n=1  }^\infty \frac{(-1)^nz^{(2n-2)}}{(2n-1)!} \right)^{-1}$ to  $ \sum\limits_{n=1  }^\infty \frac{z^{(2n-2)}}{ 6^{n}}  $?

Comment: @MichaelLevy As you can see in the step before that, I developed $$\frac1{1-\frac{z^2}6+\ldots}$$ in that geometric series, since the summands after the quadratic one are negligible.

Comment: no, I do not see that you developed it in the prior step.

Comment: @MichaelLevy Develop $\;\frac1{1-\frac{z^2}6}\;$ in a geometric series, which you can do since we can assume $\;\left|\frac{z^2}6\right|<1\;$ ...